# How to get password string from the update profile option of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to grab the password string (not the hash), when some user changes their password from the profile page of wordpress. How can I get the value? Any idea? I am trying to integrate wordpress with an external database, so it updates password everytime user updates their password on wordpress site. Password hashing structure is different on the external site, so I need the password string from the profile update page.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'check_passwords','profilescreen', 10, 3);

function profilescreen($user,$pass1,$pass2){
//Do something here
}
```